# Exception in template helper using global helper in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I added a global helper function with UI.registerHelper which returns a String. If I access the particular site, I can see the **correct output**, but I get the following exception:

```
Exception in template helper: http://localhost:3000/client/helpers/global_helpers.js?c1af37eca945292843a79e68a3037c17a0cfc841:18:45
http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?cf9aea283fb9b9d61971a3b466bff429f9d66d7d:2458:21
```

This is my code:

```
UI.registerHelper('levelMode', function() {
    return Games.findOne({_id: this._id}).mode ? 'Difficult' : 'Easy';
});
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding some checks:

```
UI.registerHelper('levelMode', function() {
  if (typeof Games !== 'undefined' && Games != null)
    var game = Games.findOne({_id: this._id});
    if (game != null && game.mode)
      return 'Difficult';
  return 'Easy';
});
```

My hunch is that the error stems from the cases where Games isn’t yet defined (the template is rendering before the collection is defined) or `findOne` returns `null` (nothing found). You can’t access a `mode` property of `null`.

Comment: Thank you! That did the job. Do you think that I got the correct output, because the page was rendered twice?

Comment: It’s probably rendering once before `Games` is populated, and again once `Games.findOne` returns a document. Look into Iron Router and `waitOn` to avoid the unnecessary first render.